# Trying to get started with solana-py

Tags: python, solana-py

I hope this is ok to ask here. I've been attempting to get my feet web in web3 dev stuff for awhile now. It's had fits and starts for months now. We had baby 3 a few months ago, but I'm back in the saddle now and attempting to give this another go.

All I'm trying to do right now is pull transactional data for a wallet. I have gotten the Helius API to work and I do get signatures. When I try to get transactional data though, I'm getting errors about version 0 transactions.  My solana-py version is 0.1.1.  I've tried upgrading it, but that errors out as well.

A few months ago, I spent days on this an couldn't figure it out. I tried installing different pip versions, different python versions. Nothing worked for me.  It's frustrating when you want to learn, but can't seem to make the first steps. I've had similar struggles with frameworks and learning React/NextJS.

Anyway, just wondering if someone here can help me get setup properly so I can start doing actual analysis of blockchain transactions.

I'm on:

- Windows 11
- VS Code
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- Linux version: 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
- python3.8
- solana.py version 0.1.1
- pip version 23.2.1

When I run
`pip install --upgrade solana`

it errors out

```
tradeup@MSI:~/dev/python/crossmint$ pip install --upgrade solana
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: solana in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.1)
Collecting solana
Obtaining dependency information for solana from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/ac/500682e3a69278e3b5c6539de3a5ba61ddab793346aac5ef09c55fbf39cd/solana-0.30.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
Using cached solana-0.30.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0.0,>=4.2.2 (from solana)
Using cached cachetools-4.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting construct-typing<0.6.0,>=0.5.2 (from solana)
Using cached construct_typing-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0 (from solana)
Using cached httpx-0.23.3-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting solders<0.19.0,>=0.18.0 (from solana)
Obtaining dependency information for solders<0.19.0,>=0.18.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/3d/242cbe61fbf8a3781a226c3d2f3d483227c76ae4f41d86342cf855795f5b/solders-0.18.1-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
Using cached solders-0.18.1-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting types-cachetools<5.0.0,>=4.2.4 (from solana)
Using cached types_cachetools-4.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.2.0 in /home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from solana) (4.5.0)
Collecting websockets<12.0,>=9.0 (from solana)
Using cached websockets-11.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (130 kB)
Collecting construct==2.10.68 (from construct-typing<0.6.0,>=0.5.2->solana)
Using cached construct-2.10.68.tar.gz (57 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana) (2022.12.7)
Collecting httpcore<0.17.0,>=0.15.0 (from httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Using cached httpcore-0.16.3-py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
Collecting rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3 (from httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Using cached rfc3986-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting sniffio (from httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Using cached sniffio-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting jsonalias==0.1.1 (from solders<0.19.0,>=0.18.0->solana)
Using cached jsonalias-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 kB)
Collecting h11<0.15,>=0.13 (from httpcore<0.17.0,>=0.15.0->httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Using cached h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting anyio<5.0,>=3.0 (from httpcore<0.17.0,>=0.15.0->httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Obtaining dependency information for anyio<5.0,>=3.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/55/ad4de788d84a630656ece71059665e01ca793c04294c463fd84132f40fe6/anyio-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
Downloading anyio-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in /home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3->httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana) (3.4)
Collecting exceptiongroup>=1.0.2 (from anyio<5.0,>=3.0->httpcore<0.17.0,>=0.15.0->httpx<0.24.0,>=0.23.0->solana)
Obtaining dependency information for exceptiongroup>=1.0.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/83/b71e58666f156a39fb29417e4c8ca4bc7400c0dd4ed9e8842ab54dc8c344/exceptiongroup-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
Using cached exceptiongroup-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Using cached solana-0.30.2-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Using cached solders-0.18.1-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.9 MB)
Downloading anyio-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 83.1/83.1 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached exceptiongroup-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: construct
Building wheel for construct (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [34 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in
File "", line 34, in
File "/tmp/pip-install-mcor27p1/construct_46bac369a9f346228736cc5e3df6ab58/setup.py", line 5, in
setup(
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/init.py", line 107, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 172, in setup
ok = dist.parse_command_line()
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1142, in _parse_command_opts
nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 534, in _parse_command_opts
cmd_class = self.get_command_class(command)
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in get_command_class
self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/init.py", line 208, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 843, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 28, in
from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
File "/home/tradeup/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in
import ctypes
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/init.py", line 7, in
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for construct
Running setup.py clean for construct
Failed to build construct
ERROR: Could not build wheels for construct, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

If I need to uninstall and start over, I'm willing to do that. I just would like to work on this analysis I want to do and right now I'm just stuck.

Thanks for your time and help,
TradeUp